# Align text combined with delimiters

Tags: align, delimiters

I want wo align text in mathmode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A \coloneqq \left\lbrace B \mid \text{very long text, which is to long for} \right. \\
\left. \text{one line} \right\rbrace
\end{align*}

%\begin{align*}
%A \coloneqq \left\lbrace B \mid &\text{very long text, which is to long for} \right. \\
%\left. &\text{one line} \right\rbrace
%\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How can I let "one" be placed under "very"?

Comment: And where should be the right delimiter?

Comment: @Bernard at the end of the second line

Comment: I propose a different layout, nicer looking, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here are several possibilities; the resetting of the `\textwidth` is only for the purpose of keeping the last example from "flying apart" (for that, you would need a much longer text).

note that `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so it's not necessary to load that explicitly.

note also that it's very bad form to input several different displays separately; it's done here only for pedagogical reasons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\textwidth=3.5in

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A \coloneqq \left\lbrace B \right. &\mid \text{very long text, which is to long for} \\
 & \phantom{\mid{}} \left. \text{one line} \right\rbrace
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
A \coloneqq \lbrace B \mid
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
    very long text, which is to long for\\
    one line$\rbrace$
  \end{minipage}
 \end{equation*}

\begin{multline*}
A \coloneqq \left\lbrace B \mid \text{very long text, which is to long for} \right. \\
\left. \text{one line} \right\rbrace
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: I really like your first solution. I do not like `\textwidth=3.5in` defined for the hole document. By this your third solution doesn't do what I want (in your second solution it can be put inside the `equation`.

Comment: Is there maybe a tool, which can check, if any of my 19 packages is redundant?

Comment: i only included the third option as it's frequently a reasonable alternative, and authors tend to overlook the fact that it's available.  (i know you asked for a particular alignment point.)  and as i said, the resetting of the `\textwidth` here was only to accommodate the `multline` example; it would be entirely inappropriate in an actual document.

Comment: What I wanted to say is, that I would like a solution, which defines `textwidth` only for the `multline` and not for the hole document

Comment: Your second solution actually doesn't use `left` and `right`. Without these I guess it's easy to aligning text in the `align`-environment

Comment: regarding defining a width for just the `multline`, if you'd really find that useful, i'll see what i can come up with.  re sizing of delimiters, better results can generally be obtained by using explicit sizes, `\bigl`, etc.  and re the difference between the `align` solution and the `minipage`, if this is really text, the baselines within the `minipage` are real text baselines, not spread apart as they are with `align`.  (that's also a flaw with `multline`, which was really intended for long math expressions that wouldn't fit on one line.)

Comment: I thought again about `multline` and came to the conclusion, that I would not define a width just for it. Thank you for the `minipage` thing, I used this in my solution (see answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way without the `align*` altogether.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
A \coloneqq \bigl\{ B \mid \stackunder{\text{very long text, which is to long for}}
{\text{one line} \bigr\}} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any differences without lines 9 and 10. I also don't know what `bigl` and `bigr` do more than just `big`. They don't check, if they are used together.

Comment: @Ben The gap between lines changes slightly.  Furthermore, without line 10, the gap will depend on whether there are descenders or not in the text (i.e., height/depth of the text line itself).  The gap size itself (baselineskip in the case of `L`ong stacks) is set with line 9.  The `\bigl` and `\bigr` don't affect this particular case, but it is best practice to use them for left and right, because there are some forms of adjacent content where the `l` and `r` will influence the result.

Answer (score 3):

I would fool LaTeX, doing it on one line with some `parbox` or `tabular`. I would also define a command for `set builder notation`, with variable-sized delimiters,  using the tools of `mathtools`. Here are two ways to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse, eqparbox, stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setstackgap{0pt}

 \DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A \coloneqq \left\lbrace B \mid \text{very long text, which is too long for} \right. \\
\left. \text{one line} \right\rbrace
\end{align*}
\renewcommand\Lstackgap{2.25ex}
\begin{align*}
A & \coloneqq \set*{ B ; \eqparbox{TB}{very long text, which is too long \\[-0.5ex]for one line}}\\[2ex]
A & \coloneqq \set[\Big]{ B ; \Centerstack[l]{very long text, which is too long \\for one line}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your definition of `set`. Now I actually wonder, if there is a package, which supports (singleline) sets. Your different layout also looks nice to me, maybe I will change it later. But your solutions seem quite complicated.

Comment: It *is* a single line set (from outside the set). This code was adapted from the code in `mathtools`  documentation. What I changed with `xparse` (the ‘complicated’ way) is to have the two arguments (before the  ‘such that’ and after) as a single argument in two parts, separated by a `;`, just as one writes by hand. More complex code, but simpler use.

Comment: I think, that the textlines are to close to each other, aren't they? I added an answer, which solves this

Comment: They were set close to each other on purpose. If you don't like it, you just have to remove `[-0.5ex]` for the first variant, and remove  `\renewcommand{\Lstackgap}{2.25ex}` for the second variant, or set it to a larger value (a normal `\baselineskip` is about `3ex`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to barbara, Bernard and Steven.

I tried to get the best of all your solutions: (What do you think about it?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\set}[3]{\left\lbrace #2 \left\vert \: \minipage{#1}{#3}\endminipage \right. \right\rbrace}

\begin{document}

\[ A \coloneqq \set{0.5\textwidth}{B}{very long text, which is too long for one line} \]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]